# Can I use category_group to relate groups with Stash's context?

Tags: stash, category-group

I cannot seem to get this to work. Can stash utilize {category_group} as a context variable?

```
{!-- Premium Member Feed --}
{exp:channel:entries channel="dba_member" status="premium" orderby="random" dynamic="off"}
    {exp:stash:append_list name="thumbs_list" context='{category_group}'}
        {stash:thumb}{snippet:members_thumbs}{/stash:thumb}
    {/exp:stash:append_list}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{!-- /Premium Member Feed --}

{exp:stash:set name="mainContent"}
    <h2>Featured Businesses</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="box-grid">                       
                <h3>Dining</h3>                                     
                {exp:stash:get_list name="thumbs_list" context='3' limit="3"}{thumb}{/exp:stash:get_list}
                <h3>Nightlife</h3>  
                {exp:stash:get_list name="thumbs_list" context='2' limit="3"}{thumb}{/exp:stash:get_list}
                <h3>Shops and Services</h3> 
                {exp:stash:get_list name="thumbs_list" context='5' limit="3"}{thumb}{/exp:stash:get_list}
            </ul>   
        </div>  
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Also then, if possible, how can I limit or "get" 3 of each {category_group} these without stashing hundreds of entries or will there not really be a performance hit? I was thinking if I limited the channel entries to "9" that it may not fetch 3 in each context of the stash list.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="dba_member" limit="9" status="premium" orderby="random" dynamic="off"}
```

Comment: I DO realize that {category_group} is not an available variable out of the box in a channel entry tag.

Comment: It is actually available though, via the categories tag pair variable: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories-tag-pair-variables

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `{categories}{category_group}{/categories}` inside your context like so:

```
{exp:stash:append_list name="thumbs_list" context='{categories}{category_group}{/categories}'}
```

Another possible option:

You could rid yourself of Context all together but, still use the category_group setup I mentioned yet, this time in a Stash var. Then do a match against in your get_list.

For example in your Stash append_list you would have something like this:

```
{exp:stash:append_list name="thumbs_list"}
    {stash:thumb}{snippet:members_thumbs}{/stash:thumb}
    {stash:this_category_group}{categories}{category_group}{/categories}{/stash:this_category_group}
{/exp:stash:append_list}
```

And in your view you would have this for each item:

```
<h3>Dining</h3>                                     
{exp:stash:get_list name="thumbs_list" match="#^3$#" against="this_category_group" limit="3"}{thumb}{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: I have tested with "{categories}{category_group}{/categories}" which does not work. I'll give the other a shot as I think that will work.

Comment: Nate can you confirm that {category_group} tag works for you? It is outputting only '1's for me.

Comment: I wonder if you have have an entry with more than one category if you'd then be getting three category group IDs for example "3 3 3" where an entry had three categories or "3 2 3" where and entry had 3 categories two from group 3 and one from group 2. Are we working with one category per item, one category group per item or more?

Comment: An entry can and usually does have multiple categories across several groups.

Comment: maybe try this match instead match="#^.*3.*$#"

Comment: I just did this today actually though, I was using category_url_title vs category_group. This allowed me to setup the regex I think a bit easier. In your case we are dealing with numbers where as I was dealing with words that were unique. I was having the same issue where it was giving back the category_url_title combined if the entry belonged to multiple cats.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6683/discussion-between-natetronn-and-wedodan)